# Find whether Alpha/beta build in code

Tags: android, xamarin

Does anyone know of a way in code to find out whether the currently running Android app has been downloaded from an Alpha/Beta channel in the Play Store?

Comment: No but you could upload separate APKs for those respective modes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no direct way to know if your app is downloaded from Alpha/Beta channel, but you can check it by the apk build number since it need to be unique across channel and the Alpha/Beta channel build number will be higher than the production one.